# Error issue during booting

Tags: boot

My computer is showing an error when I'm trying to start the system. Can anyone tell me what's going on and how to resolve it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From `man fsck`:

> fsck is used to check and optionally repair one or more Linux  filesystems.   filesys  can  be  a device name (e.g.  /dev/hdc1, /dev/sdb2), a
> mount point (e.g.  /, /usr, /home), or an ext2 label or UUID  specifier
> (e.g.   UUID=8868abf6-88c5-4a83-98b8-bfc24057f7bd or LABEL=root).  Nor‐
> mally, the fsck program will try to  handle  filesystems  on  different
> physical  disk  drives  in  parallel to reduce the total amount of time
> needed to check all of them.

1. At the prompt, type `fsck /dev/sda6` and press Enter.
2. Enter y to all the errors to fix them
3. `exit`

Comment: After entering the command it says " sh: fsck/dev/sda6: not found".

Comment: There's a space after fsck:  `fsck /dev/sda6`

Comment: Yes! The issue has been resolved. Thanks man :)

Comment: Great! Please consider accepting the answer if it helped you.